# AngularJs Individual watches vs watchCollection

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to optimize some parts of an app I've made, and I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to watch a set of parameters:

say we have the following object:

```
vm.search = {
  query : '',
  item1: ''
};
```

would it be most performant to do:

**$watch() x2**

```
$scope.$watch('vm.search.query', function(newv, oldv) {
    // process value        
});
$scope.$watch('vm.search.item', function (newv, oldv) {
    // process value
});
```

Pros:

- Only checking the value when it changes
- only need to process the value that changed

Cons:

- Need a lot of watchers if having lot's of values

---

**$watch(, true)**

```
$scope.$watch('vm.search', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (!angular.equals(newVal.query, oldVal.query)) {
        // process value
    }
    if (!angular.equals(newVal.item, oldVal.item)) {
        // process value
    }
}, true);
```

Pros:

- One watcher for all values
- When multiple changes at once, only one watcher is called

Cons:

- Checks reference which is probably not needed in this case
- need to manually check which value has changed

---

**$watchCollection()**

```
$scope.$watchCollection('vm.search', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (!angular.equals(newVal.query, oldVal.query)) {
        // process value
    }
    if (!angular.equals(newVal.item, oldVal.item)) {
        // process value
    }
});
```

Pros:

- One watcher for all values
- When multiple changes at once, only one watcher is called

Cons:

- Doesn't check reference
- Need to manually check which value has changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to watch them for different purpose, watch them in different $watch. If not you can use a $watchCollection.

Otherwise if you want to check like 5 properties you'll have a long function doing 5 different things (at least!). Better to keep them has having a single responsability.

Unless you're doing a really huge (way too huge ?) page, having some more $watch is nothing.